# Running PHPUnit Tests in Separate Processes

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, zend-studio, zend-debugger

I'm working on an AOP framework so I need to redeclare some environment variables and re-include files which are re-compiled by the framework on each test. I'm trying to run each test in a separate process so that I can do this but I'm not sure of how to do this in Zend Studio.

I've added the `@runTestsInSeparateProcesses` annotation to my tests but this causes the tests to fail with the error message:

```
testName: [Zend Debugger] Cannot receive start command
```

Has anyone been able to solve this error or find another way to run each test in a separate process in Zend?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm experiencing it right now... :(

Comment: No, unfortunately I never did @Nostradamnit.

Answer (score 0):

zend debugger is not super hot with phpunit. If possible use xdebug instead.